# Better way to show all page links than passing in a very large :inner_window value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Currently, to show all pagination links, I use

```
<%= will_paginate @collection, :inner_window => @collection.total_entries/@per_page %>
```

Is there a better* way to show all page links than passing in a very large `:inner_window` value?

** by 'better', I mean a way that is more intention revealing*

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable. You could patch the gem with some sort of `:show_all_pages => true` option and see if they'd add it...

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll do that if it turns out there isn't something like it already.